# Avoid a "Google Maps" map embedded into a web page to store cookies

Tags: google-maps, iframe, cookies

I have a simple web site page with a map (from [Google Maps](https://www.google.it/maps)) embedded into an iFrame.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed? .... ></iframe>
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cc8vjxv/) as example.

Embedding the map into the page results in **Google's cookies being stored** on the client's browser.

**Is there any way to avoid that?**

---

**Why I'm asking this:**

in the EU a web site that stores 3rd party cookies on the user's device is required to get informed consent from the user and give her/him discretion to read a long document about cookies and privacy. See [Cookies - European commission](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm)

A web site that uses only session cookies (non persistent) is **not** required to get informed consent.

There are many simple websites whose purpose is just to give basic online presence to commercial activities such as restaurants, shops and so on.

Normally those websites only need session cookies (or no cookies at all).

However as many of them use embedded Google Maps' maps to show their location they automatically fall into the category of "*websites that stores 3rd party cookies*" and must obey all the EU obligations regarding that. I think too much overhead for just displaying a map.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe you can use cookieless google maps v3:

https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2011/10/a-grab-bag-of-maps-api-news.html

> The eagle eyed amongst you may have spotted that we have updated all of our documentation to recommend that the Maps APIs be loaded from maps.googleapis.com rather than maps.google.com or maps-api-ssl.google.com. When loaded from maps.googleapis.com, the current implementation of the Maps API v3 does not rely on the exchange of cookies with Google. This improves both the security of the API, and the performance on bandwidth constrained networks. We therefore recommend all sites switch to using maps.googleapis.com.

Link to tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: silly question - this is not free isn't it ? Or just like 90 days trial ?

Comment: @FenixAoras Take a look at pricing table: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing
It looks like you can use for free 200$ bucks montly equivalent of services.

Comment: This also works for maps embedded via iframes.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a very fast way of doing this, which could be also helpful.
This site creates a cookie less iframe which can be place for instance, in a visual composer for wordpress maps container
https://www.uwp.is.ed.ac.uk/3rd-party-widgets/maps/

I've tested it and it won't load NID cookie, so no need to get consent for it.

Hope it helps

Comment: The service is managed by the University of Edinburgh and claims to generate a OpenStreetMap interactive map (served by University) with no privacy-invasive cookies. Alas, the **service is reserved to the sites related to the University**. Currently, the OSM generated map will not get served by the University's servers to unidentified website, and will result in a warning stating "Interactive map disabled". A proper answer here would be explain how they designed their service, since embedding a OSM map normally also results in their (third party) cookies being stored on the client's browser...