# Google Maps Embed without cookies

Tags: cookies

I'm currently using a Google Maps embed on my website like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).

It shows me the correct position as well as raitings, opening hours and so on.
The only problem I have is that it places some cookies which I am not allowed to use (EU law, it would require some specific informations I do not want to display).

I already read some threads where people advised to use Google Maps API V3 but I can't figure out how to display the exact same informations like icon, raiting.

Is there any way to remove those cookies using the iframe method?

Comment: Still looking for a solution

Comment: You can find teh solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995225/avoid-a-google-maps-map-embedded-into-a-web-page-to-store-cookies?rq=1

Comment: Thats not a solution for me. I don't need a "blank" with custom Marker, but the precreated Google Maps embed.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you meant the iframe solution! In case it is an option for you - you might start a new question how to build the same using google maps V3 API? Using custom markers isn't hard and regarding the ratings it looks like you need to activate the Google Places API Webservice combined with targeting it in your javascript. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: Im able to get raiting as a number, but not a graphical solution like illustrated in "stars"...